# Warning: require(file): failed to open stream

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu, lamp

I've changed development machines and have moved across one of my projects.  However, when I try to run one of the files in this project, I get the following error message:

```
Warning: require(/var/www/libraries/facebook.php): failed to open stream: Permission denied in /var/www/logout.php on line 11 Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/libraries/facebook.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php:/usr/share/pear') in /var/www/logout.php on line 11
```

Anyone know why this would be happening?

It might be that I have the permissions set incorrectly.  What should the file and folder permissions be?

All files are currently set to `-rw-r--r--` and folders are set to `drwx------`, is that right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes when things get moved paths can change. The error indicates that the file '/var/www/libraries/facebook.php' could not be found. Make sure that the file exists in that location.

Sometimes the web server runs with different credentials than the user. Try setting the directories to drwxr-x---, and the files to -rw-r--r--. If that doesn't work, then try changing the directories to drwxr-xr-x.

Comment: Done, file exists, might be permissions?  All files are set to `-rw-r--r--` and folders are set to `drwx------`, is that right?

Comment: Sometimes the web server runs with different credentials than the user. Try setting the directories to drwxr-x---, and the files to -rw-r--r--. If that doesn't work, then try changing the directories to drwxr-xr-x.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a Permission denied error which means that your libraries folder can only be accessed by the root user. Try to execute the script as a root user or give read permissions to the folder.

```
## use only for files ##
chmod 0444 /var/www/*
chmod 0444 /var/www/*.php
```

TO set directories in read-only mode, enter:

```
## use only for dirs ##
chmod 0544 /var/www/
chmod 0444 /path/to/your/dir/
```

Answer (score 0):

You say the permissions are drwx------.  Try changing to the /var/www/libraries directory in the shell as a non-root user.  If you get an error there, the web server will also.  You might need 755 permissions so the server can traverse to that directory.  Just be careful what else is in that folder since it could be readable by the whole world.